# How can I create object of certain (big) size?

Tags: c#

I wonder if there's a way to create let's say 1 MB object other than a very big list. It could be anything as long as it's reference type.
I want to use it in memory profiler tests so I don't need any special behavior. Maybe some unit test engine or Moq have such feature?

Comment: Welcome to SO [ask]

Answer (score 2):

An array is pretty straightforward to create.

```
Console.WriteLine($"Allocated memory: {GC.GetTotalMemory(false)}");
var array = new byte[1024 * 1024];
Console.WriteLine($"Allocated memory: {GC.GetTotalMemory(false)}");
```

Output:

```
Allocated memory: 160872
Allocated memory: 1209504
```